# Preventing POST flood on Django forms

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django web app (with nginx webserver) where users can post interesting status messages.

Some users are using scripts to do a POST flood. I have `fail2ban` implemented, so these seldom last longer than 2-3 secs. But I need to know whether there are other ways I can stop a non-human POSTer. Like imagine text as follows suddenly popping up on the website:

```
6:07.371806+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772081 | Hfd                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
7:01.909866+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772090 | ...                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
7:11.392105+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772110 | .....                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
7:33.172462+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772119 | Kokjhd                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
7:43.189524+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772128 | Hfs                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
7:52.209139+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772171 | Lloo                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
8:34.195006+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772178 | Kkjh                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
8:42.976177+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772211 | Kkkkkk                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
9:17.003594+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772230 | Kmkkkjhhf                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                 |           8322 |     11880 | 2016-03-14 09:0
9:33.680043+00 |                                                  | 0        | 2
 2772238 | Lkkk
```

My form is quite vanilla. E.g.:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.description }}<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Is there any way at all I can nullify such behavior in my code? I know about honeypots used to keep spam bots at bay for instance, but malicious human handlers of scripts designed to flood my app won't fall for that. I might be missing something fundamental here?

Note that many-a-time the floods are of the sort `., .., ..., ...., ....., ......, .......` (i.e. repetitive characters, with minor changes to side-step my logic which doesn't let the user post the same thing twice). Can I set up something that curtails POST requests where the content matches the previous POST from the same user with 95% accuracy? Ever heard of or tried something like that? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to throttle user requests. Have a look at [Django Throttle Requests](http://django-throttle-requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html)

Comment: Okay that's another layer, aside from fail2ban. Also, many-a-time the floods are of the sort `., .., ..., ...., ....., ......, .......` (i.e. repetitive, with minor changes to side-step my logic which doesn't let the user post the same thing twice). Can I set up a regex that curtails POST requests where the content matches the previous POST from the same user with 95% accuracy? Ever heard of or tried something like that?

Comment: While I understand your problem @HassanBaig, there is no thin solution to this. I'm sure you do understand that regex can't solve this problem - unless you decide to build regex's dynamically out of request contents.

Comment: Your best bet would be to implement a server side validation that ensures a minimal match with (say) prev 10 posts in the last hour.  Of course, that and throttling - because you don't want bots posting 100 requests/min (all very different, but meaningless).

Comment: What about any kind of fuzzy string matching?

Comment: yes, but today you're getting `., .., ...,` but you can't be sure to have a similar pattern next month or even next week. Given the nature of the problem - you need to continuously adapt. In a previous employment, we tried to learn regex out of spam in comments, but that quickly turned out to be quite a big research problem.

Comment: In most cases, however, it is easiest (and usually enough!) to implement a combination of: (a) good basic validation method (b) user/ip throttling and (c) some form of request history driven validation.

Comment: Well I had something like https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy in mind. Compare the previous string with the current one, and if there's a match above a certain level of fuzziness, don't let the user POST. That kind of a scheme. Anywho, I get the strategy you've defined. (c) is intriguing. Any specifics on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106818/discussion-between-zero-and-hassan-baig).